# Applying multiple regexes in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a big log file. I have to apply multiple regexes one by one and before printing the output of each regex i need to print some text.

For eg.

After applying the regexes, I should get output something like this:

```
Text 1

Output of first regex
....


Text 2 

Output of second regex
....

Text 3

Output of third regex
....
```

where Text 1, Text 2 and Text 3 are my inserted texts. Can we achieve this using AWK.

**Edit:**

I am adding part of the sample log file.

```
[1351059075] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351059898] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351073883] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL 
[1351073886] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL
[1351088949] SERVICE ALERT: server3:PSU ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
```

Now I want to separate all `Email` , `History`, `PSU` so my output should look like this:

```
Email:

[1351059075] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351059898] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused

History:

[1351073883] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL 
[1351073886] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL

PSU:

[1351088949] SERVICE ALERT: server3:PSU ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
```

I wrote a simple awk script:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Email:\n\n"} /SERVICE ALERT: .*Email.*CRITICAL;HARD/ {print $0}' logfilename
```

I dont know how to include multiple regexes in the same awk script so as to print in the desired way.

Comment: yes you can acheive this with awk, but we have no idea how to help you. Please include simplified sample data, and required output based on that sample data. ALSO include the code you have tried to execute, error messages or descriptions of why your output doesn't satisfy your requirements. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Added the required data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask to do is trivial (just add more /RE/{action} lines) but your approach of using REs is wrong in the first place. All you need to do is this:

```
$ cat file
[1351059075] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351059898] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351073883] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL
[1351073886] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL
[1351088949] SERVICE ALERT: server3:PSU ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS = "[:;]" }
{ out[$3] = out[$3] $0 ORS }
END { for (type in out) print type ORS out[type] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Email
[1351059075] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351059898] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused

PSU
[1351088949] SERVICE ALERT: server3:PSU ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused

History
[1351073883] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL
[1351073886] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following command (is a one-liner split in varios lines):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        FS = "[:;]"; 
    } 
    {
        if ( $3 in keys ) {
            printf "%s\n", $0;
        }
        else {
            printf "%s%s:\n\n%s\n", (length( keys ) > 0) ? "\n" : "", $3, $0;
        }

        keys[ $3 ] = 1;
    }
' infile
```

That yields:

```
Email:

[1351059075] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
[1351059898] SERVICE ALERT: server1:Email;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused

History :

[1351073883] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL 
[1351073886] SERVICE ALERT: server2:History ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;HTTP CRITICAL

PSU :

[1351088949] SERVICE ALERT: server3:PSU ;CRITICAL;HARD;3;Connection refused
```

Comment: A few isues: 1) the semi-colons at the end of the lines are adding null statements, not terminating the lines, 2) the use of length(array) makes it GNU awk specific, 3) you shouldn't assign 1 to keys[$3] as it's clearer that you're creating a set if you don't, and 4) the idiomatic awk way of testing for a value being present in a set is to use keys[$3]++ as a condition rather than testing it at one line and then populating it later.

Comment: @EdMorton: **1)** I don't understand what do you mean in this first point. **2)** Are you sure that `length` doesn't work with non-GNU versions of `awk`? It appears in its man page. **3)** `keys[ $3 ] = 1` is neccesary in this program because I want to print header in first line only, and I use it as a flag. **4)** Yes, I'm not used to that expression, but seems much better. I will try to remember for next time.

Comment: 1) In C "foo;" means "do foo" since ";"s terminate statements but in awk it means "do foo" and then "do nothing" - it's 2 separate unrelated statements. 2) yes. it might work in tawk too but that's not available for download any more. You're probably reading the gawk man page. Try adding the "--posix" flag to your command line. 3) You're using "keys" as a set - change your line to just "keys[$3]" with no assignment and you'll see that it still works but the code intent is clearer. 4) OK.

Comment: To clarify '1)" - writing "foo;" in awk is like writing "foo;;" in C. You can do it and it'll compile but it's wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton: Ok. Thank you. I tested both points. The `length` function with `--posix` only works with strings, not arrays :-)

Comment: Right. That was my comment, that using length(array) is gawk-only.